# How to set a code that find the half price of the previous candle?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to set a code that finds the middle price of the previous candle and draw a line on it.

I searched about it and found that using: `(open[1] + close[1]) / 2` Finds the middle of the candle, but my problem is that I don't know how to use it with another value..

For example, if we are using this simple EMA code:

```
indicator(title="EMA 20/50/100", overlay=true)

shortest = ta.ema(close, 5)

short = ta.ema(close, 10)

longer = ta.ema(close, 20)

plot(shortest, color=color.yellow, linewidth=2)

plot(short, color=color.red, linewidth=2)

plot(longer, color=color.purple, linewidth=2)
```

And we set a simple code to find the candles where (shortest) line crosses over (short):

```
EmaCross = ta.crossover(shortest, short)
```

Now the question is, how can we set a code so whenever (EmaCross) value happens in the previous candle, it draws a line in the middle of that candle using ((open[1] + close[1]) / 2)? The idea is that if we buy on (EmaCross), we'd have a stop loss with ((open[1] + close[1]) / 2) by selling if the price went down to the middle of the (EmaCross) candle...

I think we can use (ta.valuewhen) but I don't know how to use it exactly to achieve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `var` keyword keeps the value of a variable until you change actively change it.
We can use this in order to determine the value and than later `plot` it on to the chart. For example:

```
var float middleBody = na

if EmaCross
    middleBody := (open[1] + close[1]) / 2
```

If we `plot` the variable `middleBody`, we will get a line of the middle of the body that will change only when `EmaCross` will be true.

I believe this answers your question, but we can do better than that. We can assign `na` when something happens, and then use the `plot` function. That way, we can ignore the line if the condition is not met. for example:

```
EmaCrossUnder = ta.crossunder(shortest, short)

if EmaCrossUnder or ta.crossunder(close, nz(middleBody))
    middleBody := na
```

The `nz` function is used, since `middleBody` can be `na`, so this function will replace `na` with 0.

Now we can `plot` the variable `middleBody` and use the `style` parameter of the `plot` function so it won't connect the line if there is an `na` value:

```
plot(middleBody, color=color.lime, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Here's the full code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="EMA 20/50/100", overlay=true)

shortest = ta.ema(close, 20)
short = ta.ema(close, 50)
// longer = ta.ema(close, 20)

plot(shortest, color=color.yellow, linewidth=2)
plot(short, color=color.red, linewidth=2)
// plot(longer, color=color.purple, linewidth=2)

EmaCross = ta.crossover(shortest, short)


var float middleBody = na

if EmaCross
    middleBody := (open[1] + close[1]) / 2
    
EmaCrossUnder = ta.crossunder(shortest, short)

if EmaCrossUnder or ta.crossunder(close, nz(middleBody))
    middleBody := na


plot(middleBody, color=color.lime, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, you're a legend. Thank you!